# python decorate function call

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

Is it possible to wrap a function call using python decorators?

I don't want to implement a wrapper for every function of a module individually.

I would like to have something like

```
def a(num):
    return num

@double_the_value
a(2)
```

returning `4` without the need of having access to the implementation of `a`.

Would a global wrapper like

```
def multiply(factor, function, *args, **kwargs):
    return factor * function(*args, **kwargs)
```

be the better choice in this case?

Comment: I'd use your `multiply(factor, function)`, since what you're asking is not possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the `@decorator` syntax is only available to be used in conjunction with the definition of a function or class, the syntax before decorators became a language feature can do what you request:

```
from module import myfunc

myfunc = double_decorator(myfunc)

x = myfunc(2) # returns 4
```

---

**Further Reading:** There is a very good detailed section on decorators in Marty Alchin's book *Pro Python* from Apress.

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like that:

```
def a(num):
    return num * 1

def double(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

print(double(a)(2))
```

It's because we can decorate functions and run functions using a decorator function explicit as in the example above.
So in this one:

```
print(double(a)(2))
```

In the place of `a` you can put any function and in place of the `2`, args and kwargs.

Comment: How would I use that now together with the @ syntax?

Comment: In your case you can't. You can use @ syntax only on function declaration.

Comment: @turkus: perhaps you should change it so that the wrapper actually returns double the value? `return 2 * f(*args, **kwargs)`. Or call the decorator something else, like do_nothing.

Answer (score -3):

I find that a useful approach is to define a new function that is decorated

```
def my_function():
    pass

@my_decorator
def my_function_with_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    my_function()

my_function() # call without decorator

my_function_with_decorator() # call with decorator
```